# How to add event listener to the element with updated class?

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why my [script](http://jsfiddle.net/2ood20aj/) doesn't work. I change the class of div and try to listen the event binded to the elem by class name.

```
$('.glyphicon-minus').on('click', function () {
    var item = $(this).closest('.item');
    var child = $(item).children('.item-content');
    $(child).hide();
    $(this).removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus');
});


$('.glyphicon-plus').on('click', function () {
    var item = $(this).closest('.item');
    var child = $(item).children('.item-content');
    debugger;
    $(child).show();
    $(this).removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bindings are already set so the new class addition isn't considered. You need to abstract your bindings up the DOM tree and delegate them down to the dynamic nodes :

Change `$('.glyphicon-plus').on('click',`

to `$('.some-permanent-container-div').on('click', '.glyphicon-plus',`

If you recall several years ago people used `$('.my-div').live('click'` to achieve this, but all that did was attach the binding to `document` and delegate. It's much more efficient to bind to the closest static container and delegate as few child tiers down as possible.

Comment: Oh, when I write instead of `$('.glyphicon-plus').on('click', function (){...})` this line `$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-plus', function () {...})` all works fine.